# How to defend my API against Sentry.io Curl timeout?

Tags: php, curl, timeout, sentry

I am using the PHP Sentry SDK within an API (and the JS client too at the front-end), and today I experienced an error caused by a Curl timeout which I presume is the Sentry SDK client talking back to their host. While I don't have a full stack trace, I do not use Curl for anything else.

I've been using Sentry for several months, and not noticed this before.

There wasn't actually an application error at the time, so I guessed Sentry was just connecting anyway which surprised me. I thought it would only even run on trapping an error. I only have the basic free account with just "Issues" no "Events".

It seemed to stick for so long that the 30s PHP max execution time expired, so I got a 500 error from my API. (Actually the 500 error must have come from Apache, it didn't seem to be trapped by the shutdown+error handler I've installed. )

`[17-Jan-2020 02:07:40 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in api/vendor/php-http/curl-client/src/MultiRunner.php on line 87`

I have basic boot config:
`Sentry\init(['dsn' => $config['sentry_dsn']]);`

It seems ironic that my error handling should break the API occasionally! So I want to defend myself from this - even if it's rare.

**Is it possible to add some configuration to Sentry or Curl e.g. to quit gracefully after 10 seconds max?**

I couldn't see anything here:
https://docs.sentry.io/error-reporting/configuration/?platform=php

Or is there another way to make Sentry more "background" so it cannot block the main code path?

Comment: Still got this issue? have you found a fix?

Comment: @Hackbard no I haven't found a fix, but I haven't experienced it again. Although I'm not using this PHP project, I have been using Sentry in JS both backend node and front end continually for years now and have never seen a similar issue. So Sentry's servers seem super stable. I am guessing the above problem was on my end which was hosted at a pretty cheap host and perhaps they had a network issue - it's more likely.